# Xamarin iOS Object reference error when calling method in another View Controller

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

Need some help with a object instance problem when using Xamarin iOS.  My App starts with a Tab bar controller holding 2 navigation controllers.  Each navigation controller has its own View Controller called `A_ViewController` and `B_ViewController`.

`A_ViewController` has a button which when clicked will navigate to `B_ViewController`.

`B_ViewController` has a Text Field which I want to update with a value from the button press in `A_ViewController`.

In `B_ViewController`  I have a method that does the Text Field update when I call it from `A_ViewController`.

I get a Null reference error when I run this and I'm not sure why.  I've instantiated `B_ViewController` so I should be able to update the Text field by calling `bvc.UpdateTextField()`.

```
class A_ViewController : UIViewController {
    partial void btnUpdate_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender) {
        var bvc = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("BVC") as B_ViewController;
        bvc.UpdateTextField();
        NavigationController.PushViewController(bvc, true);
    }
}



class B_ViewController : UIViewController {
    public void UpdateTextField(){
        myTextField.Text = "Hello World";  <-- System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    }
}
```

Comment: if you have a tabcontroller with 2 child controllers A & B, then when you create a new instance of B from within A, that is NOT the same instance of B that exists in the other tab.  It's a completely new instance.  And you get a null reference because instantiating B does not guarantee that all of it's child controls have been created yet.

Comment: Thanks Jason.  Makes sense that I'm referencing a new instance.  Still not sure how I can get the instance of B from A to execute the update method.

Comment: the easiest way is to pass an instance of B to A when you create it.  Or you could try using a messaging framework

Comment: Close to my final solution, I ended storing the values I needed in NSUserDefaults and in B, I used override ViewWillAppear to read NSUserDefaults to retrieve the values everytime the view loaded.  This worked out better as I completely decoupled the 2 view controllers from each other.  Thanks.